# Django - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'csvexport'

Tags: python, django, python-poetry

So I'm working on adding an admin function to a Django project so that I can export the model instances to csv. It is all working fine locally whilst using Docker. But when deploying I get this internal server error:[image]

It states that the package is not installed, but when accessing the Django shell (poetry run python3 manage.py shell) and importing the package (from csvexport.actions import csvexport) everything works fine. I'm stuck for quite some time now on this and cant figure out what is going wrong. Anyone had some kind of problem like this with poetry package managing?

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'csvexport',
]
```

model:

```
from csvexport.actions import csvexport
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin

class FundAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = [csvexport]
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Please don’t use images of errors; include the plain text. Why is your server’s  `venv` installed under a cache directory? Have you tried activating it and attempting the import from there, not with poetry?

Comment: I think the most serious question is - is he using Docker on production? If no, is he running it under virtualenv? If yes, it's activated or not? It's configured correctly under Apache or not?

Comment: @PatrykSzczepański So I was actually not involved in the setup of this project, I took it over without any documentation. I know that it is deployed on a DigitalOcean server with uWSGI and nginx.

Comment: @FlipperPA when typing '/home/vfs/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vfs-gOLk6wo--py3.7/bin/pip freeze --local'  I can see the package in there: django-admin-csvexport==1.11

Comment: @Lookszz How about `source /home/vfs/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vfs-gOLk6wo--py3.7/bin/activate && source /home/vfs/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vfs-gOLk6wo--py3.7/bin/python` and then `from csvexport.actions import csvexport` at the Python CLI? It looks to me like you're not using Docker in production (good, it's another layer you don't need on a Digital Ocean VM).

Comment: Okay then I get this @FlipperPA:
```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CSV_EXPORT_DELIMITER, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: @FlipperPA does this mean I need to do something before changing settings? I did make changes in settings.py and didn't have any problems, I attached the manage.py in the post.

Comment: @FlipperPA Can you still help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-csvexport/), seems you followed the steps apart from `pip install django-admin-csvexport`, so my only assumption is that you have not installed the requirement. Can you try adding this to your requirements?

Comment: I did this, I just think it is not installed in the right place for some reason